# Android: How to open an email received on a mail account?

Tags: android, email

Android: programmatically - how to open an email received on mail account (for example, gmail). Like in BlackBerry, there is ViewListener interface, which has `open()` and `close()` methods. Is there any similar interface in Android as well. Please advise.

Comment: Step 1) Make Shorter Title. Step 2) Solve Problem. Step 3) **PROFIT!!!**

Comment: I did not got what u meat to say by Solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on Android -- sorry!

Comment: When I opened Emulator (android). I can see email application, to which I configure my Outlook account. Now, I want to create an application, such that when I open a mail of my Outlook a/c (thru the email application of android), it should Open a web-browser or it should do something else. rather then displaying the message content on opening of mail.  Is there is API of android that will help in this scenario.
Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: This is not possible on Android -- sorry!